# What is the default charset of a spring-boot response

Tags: java, spring-boot, utf-8, content-type, charset

The below is the controller method I use:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/v1/my-api",
        produces = { "application/json" }, 
        method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<EmployeeObject> getEmployee(@RequestParam String id){
    
   // code here

}
```

So, as I have configured the property `produces = { "application/json" }`, I wanted to know what is the charset encoding of the response of this API, is it **UTF-8** by default ?

Comment: I realize I'm avoiding your question, but why not just change your code from `produces = { "application/json" },` to `produces = { "application/json;charset=utf8" }, `. That's a win-win: you guarantee that you will get utf8, and your code is explicit and self-documenting. Or is there some reason you prefer to rely on the default being utf8?

Comment: Agreed, will follow this for new APIs. However the end user wants to know the charset for this API as they are facing some encoding issues..

Comment: OK, gotcha. Your question is deceptively simple, because I think it's tricky to infer the default charset/encoding in a Spring Boot environment, unless the documentation for your specific release makes that clear. A few things that might be relevant for your specific situation would include O/S, console environment (if any), your Spring Boot version and your JDK version (see [JEP 400: UTF-8 by Default](https://openjdk.org/jeps/400)). Is it possible to update your question to include some expected and actual data for your end user with the problem, and details of their environment?